# URL Hacking - "null" value displayed for dependent field instead of "None"

Tags: urlhacking

I have a created a custom list button on the opportunity standard page. All the fields that I wanted are populated correctly from the parent opportunity.(through url hacking)

I have a controlling field on the parent opportunity which I set to a value using URL hacking, but i don't want to set anything to its corresponding dependent picklist field. When I click this button,  the controlling field is populated with the correct value, but the dependent field is selected with "null" value instead of "None" (Standard value which gets selected for mandatory field when we create new records.

How do I display "None" as the selected value when I hit my new custom button (URL Hacking)..

Comment: Can you post a copy of the url in question? Also, have you tried setting the dependent value through the url as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry never mind. I figured out the issue. The issue was with my url string, where I was hard coding the dependent field to a value which is not valid pick list option.

Sorry for the trouble.